# Expose Rails App Environment to Ruby Script

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Out of pure curiosity, I am wondering if it's possible (no doubt it is) to 'hook into' a Rails Application's environment. So for example, say I want to create a cron script (I don't) that operates some sort of maintenance on a Rails app, and I want to write it in Ruby and using all of the nice code that I already have, for example, `User.find` etc.

Is this possible, and if so, how?

I'm just curious, as I feel I would eventually want to do this for some reason or other.

I'm currently on Rails 3 with Ruby 1.9.1, in case it matters.

Comment: Isn't this what the Rails console does? You could take a look at the source for that to see how it's done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is certainly possible. Here is a good writeup on how to do that: [How to run a rake task from cron](http://wiki.joyent.com/smartmachine%3arails%3acron)

Comment: I don't want to create a cron job, that was just an example. Anyways, so I take it this is how you do it? By integrating the code into a rake task? Seems simple enough, thanks!

Comment: It seems that the 'trick' to get this to work, is to designate the task as: task :mytask => :environment, then one will have access to the environment.

Comment: Yeah, once you do that you have access to the environment. I do this all the time (not just with cron tasks).

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [Rails::Railtie class](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/Rails/Railtie.html). If you need to run code code when you start up your app, this is a way to do it. [Here's a very simple example.](http://www.igvita.com/2010/08/04/rails-3-internals-railtie-creating-plugins/)

Answer (score 1):

From the beginning of Rails there is ./script/runner, designed exactly for such kind of problems.

In Rails 3 you call it as: `./script/rails runner "puts User.find(:all).map(&:inspect)"`

Try `./script/runner --help` or `./script/rails runner --help`

As the argument to the runner you provide a filename or just a code.

It's often more useful than preparing a Rake task, because you can execute just one-time actions:

```
ssh prod@example.com "cd rails/app && ./script/runner -e production 'puts User.count'"
```

Answer (score 1):

You could either use *script/rails runner* as suggested by Arsen7 or you could write your own script in which you load the app environment in the beginning:

```
require 'config/environment'
```

is actually everything you need.

To have your script working in a cron job, make sure that it is executable (*chmod u+x*) and that it starts with a correct shebang line (*#!/usr/bin/env ruby* or whatever is appropriate for your situation).

Answer (score 0):

yeah just require these file at top of your script file

```
require  'config/boot.rb' 
require 'config/application.rb'
Rails.application.require_environment!
```

Now you'll have access to your models

Comment: This is actually too complicated: _require config/environment_ is enough.